# Unicode characters not showing properly on french jsp page

Tags: jsp, utf-16

I am using the UTF-16 code `"\u2013"` in my java property file to display a dash in my page. The page is in French. Now at this link:  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm I see that they say this is an 'en-dash'. What is an en-dash? A dash should  be same in en and fr I think.
On the screen, it shows up as a question mark.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**en dash** is unrelated to english language. It's named after its length (or width): a dash that is `1en` large.

There's also the **em dash**, which width is `1em`.

`1en` is the width of the letter `n`; `1em` is the width of the letter `m`. The former width is half the width of the latter (their name in french typography are resp. *tiret demi-cadratin* and *tiret cadratin*. *Demi* means half and *tiret* dash: it's quite clear that one is half the other).

Uses:

- "09:00 - 17:00" is a range and the dash should be an **[en dash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_dash)**
- "and Paris - the legendary figure of the Trojan War, not the capital of France - said to Hector" should use **[em dashes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/em_dash)** where parenthesis could've been used

Other facts:

- `em` is also a relative unit in CSS
- respective HTML entities are `&ndash;` and `&mdash;`.

As for the question mark displayed: is the font used able to display those glyphs? The dash/minus `-` is OK if the font lacks any other dash.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem due to not using UTF-8, this is a format which support all languages characters. You can use such type of conversion while displaying any type of language text. For example:

To see the exact words of this string (Votre compte Ã Ã©tÃ© activÃ©) we must convert it to UTF-8. after this it will be seeing as (Votre compte à été activé)

$text             =     'Comment utiliser du texte français en php ex: Prénom';

$enc             =     mb_detect_encoding($text, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1");

$changewords    =    iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $text);

Comment: I undeleted this to give the author a chance to edit. Please do not delete for a few days.